# How to convert File to String and get back that String to File again

Tags: java

I have a question: "How to convert File to String and get back that String to File again in Java?"

my code :

```
public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException{
    String fff = fileToString("Book.xlsx");
    byte[] bytes = fff.getBytes();

    File someFile = new File("Book2.xlsx");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(someFile);
    fos.write(bytes);
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
}

public static String fileToString(String file) {
    String result = null;
    DataInputStream in = null;

    try {
        File f = new File(file);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) f.length()];
        in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
        in.readFully(buffer);
        result = new String(buffer);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("IO problem in fileToString", e);
    } finally {
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { /* ignore it */
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

How I can getback `Book1.xlsx` in string and saved in `book2.xlsx` ?? `Book2.xlsx` is null....

Comment: We have a question: what have you tried?

Comment: It must be save to file.

Comment: A) we need to know what you need (application, some source code) B) Please expand the question C) try the FileWriter (put effort in the question and people will expand answers)

Comment: Now I see your code snippet, it seems you are treating XSLX as though they were plain text files, when they are really XML inside a Zip archive.  I suggest in future questions that you pause at the point after the read, dump the read data back to the command prompt and examine it to ensure it makes any sense.

Answer (score 2):

You have a number of choices, but the `Writer` and `Reader` interfaces make this simple.

Use a [`FileWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) to write your `String` to a `File`, like so:

```
File destination = new File("...");
String stringToWrite = "foo";
Writer writer = new FileWriter(destination);
writer.write(stringToWrite);
writer.close();
```

Then use a [FileReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) to read it back:

```
StringBuilder appendable = new StringBuilder();
Reader reader = new FileReader(destination);
reader.read(appendable);
reader.close();

String readString = appendable.toString();
```

Comment: +1 for 'raising the bar' on the answer.  Pity it was such an eminently closeable question.  Even more of a pity that it was closed 3 minutes prior to an edit that made it ..if not a *good* question, then at least one worthy of further attention.